# Multiply rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with, say, 4 rows labeled r1 through r4 and 2 columns ("c1" and "c2"). The values in this dataframe/matrix are "a*ij*" as in (pseudo-code):

```
dataframe =    c1  c2
            r1 a11 a12
            r2 a21 a22
            r3 a31 a32
            r4 a41 a42
```

I would now like to compute, in a very efficient way (think many many columns), the product of the rows.

More specifically,  I would like to form a list with number of elements equal to number of columns which, as its *i*th element has the product of all rows:

```
list_ = [a11 * a21 * a31 * a41, a12 * a22 * a32 * a42]
```

In reality I have thousands of columns, but only around 4 rows.

I looked at dataframe's "sum(...)" function (with its "axis" argument) and it is something like that I need, but in a multiplication version. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted some code we could copy into our terminals and play with. Nothing you've posted will actually run verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) which will calculate the product of all elements column-wise, you can then call `tolist` on the result as required:

```
In [23]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=list('abc'))
df
​
Out[23]:
   a   b   c
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11

In [26]:
df.prod()

Out[26]:
a      0
b    280
c    880
dtype: int64

In [25]:
df.prod().tolist()

Out[25]:
[0, 280, 880]
```

Comment: How to multiply only two specific rows (`2` and `3`, for example)?